# output in tabular format in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible in Netlogo to show the output (using print command) in table format i.e. row and column.

For example,In simulation, a day has 24 hours and in each hour there are five different attributes i.e. windspeed, temperature, humidity, visibility, and rainfall. Is it possible to show value of hours in rows and attributes values in column by using print statement or by other statement?

Answer (score 0):

From the variable names, I am assuming these are global variables rather than something attached to any particular agent. And also assuming that each hour is a tick. In this case, you could have a statement like the following in the setup procedure to provide headings:

```
type "Windspeed" type "Temperature" <other headings> print "Rainfall"
```

then a similar statement in the go procedure to provide the variable values each tick

```
type windspeed type temperature <other variables> print rainfall
```

That would output it to the window at the bottom of the interface. If you want it in a widget, have a look at the `output-type` and `output-print` commands.

Comment: Each hour is tick but other five variables are attached to particular type of agent which are located at different locations of grid.

Comment: in that case you need to do the call within an `ask whatever-you-called-the-breed [ ]` and also print the `x-cor` and `y-cor` or other identifying information